# Apache Ant add header & footer to EVERY file in concat job

Tags: ant, concatenation

I'm sure that this is trivial - but have been bashing my head against a wall
I'm trying to take a directory full of mustache templates (html files essentially) and combine them into one file - wrapping each one with a  tag

Example:

```
File1 = <a>This is a Link</a>
File2 = <b>This is in bold</b>
```

I want the output to look like:

```
<script type="text/mustache" id="File1">
 <a>This is a Link</a>
</script>
<script type="text/mustache" id="File2">
 <b>This is in bold</b>
</script>
```

I'm using a concat task

```
<concat destfile="mustache.js" fixlastline="yes">
 <fileset dir="." includes="**/*.mustache"/>
</concat>
```

but can't figure out how to get the script blocks to display

Answer (score 1):

At first i thought about using concat somehow with header and footer but didn't find a working solution.
If you not shy away from using some Ant addon, here's a solution based on **[Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka)** =

```
<project name="demo" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

 <!-- make standard ant tasks understand EL expressions -->
  <fl:install-property-handler />

  <!-- we use path instead of pure fileset because we need
       absolute filenames for loadfile later in for loop -->
  <path id="foo">
   <fileset dir="/some/path"  includes="**/*.mustache"/>
  </path>

  <!-- iterate over the path/fileset -->
  <fl:for var="file" in="split('${toString:foo}', ':')">
   <!-- unset property for next loop -->
   <fl:unset>content</fl:unset>
   <!-- load file contents to property -->
   <loadfile property="content" srcFile="#{file}"/>

   <echo file="/some/path/foobar/mustache.js" append="true">
   <!-- the id attribute gets filled with the basename of the current fileitem -->
<![CDATA[<script type="text/mustache" id="#{replace(file, '$1' , '.+?(\w+)\..+' )}">
#{trim('${content}')}
</script>]]></echo>
  </fl:for>

</project>
```

**Note** : 
1. my leftmost notation within the echo task to avoid unnecessary blanks in the resulting file !
 just write as in my example above and your file will look like your wanted output
2. the `<![CDATA[...]]>` is needed, otherwise you'll get some error like "echo doesn't support the nested "script" element."

Comment: Thanks for the thought - actually we couldn't get this to work (and gave up - used a bash script instead :(

Comment: the example does exactly what you've asked for - what didn't work for you !?